# Set page title from DataProvider value yii2

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I have a view `event` and it has a extra action button which redirects to `checkin/index` page
here is my gridview

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'id'=>'event-table',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'columns' => [
        'title',
        'location',
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
            'template' => '{checkin/index} {view} {update} {delete} ',
            'contentOptions' => ['class'=>'action-td'],

            'buttons' => [
                'checkin/index' => function ($url,$model) {
                    return Html::a('<div id="notification-container"><span data-pjax=false class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>'.EventSearch::showCheckin($model->id) .'</div>', $url,['data-pjax' => true]);
                },
            ]
        ],
    ]
]);
```

When use clicks on that button it will open a `checkin/index` page
so i want to send the `title` of the row on which the button was clicked so that 
on the `checkin/index` page i can use that title as `$this->title`

is there any way to pass data on action button click
here is my `checkin/index` code

```
public function actionIndex()
{

    $searchModel = new CheckinSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

I cannot use below code because my `$model` will only have value of `event_id` as related table and on `checkin/index` page i use gridview and relation to display title directly using `event.title`

```
$this->title = isset($dataProvider->models[0]->title) ? $dataProvider->models[0]->title : 'empty result';
```

Comment: You want to pass data with url?

Comment: @InsaneSkulll i just need to set the title of the page.. Anyhow i can... Flow is like this... in the row of `event/index` gridview user will click on the action column button and it will open `checkin/index` page for that particular record... so i want to get the title of the row where user clicked and pass it to next page to set the page title

Comment: you can simple pass the data with url and get them on desire page and pass it  to page title.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll yeah  but how.. i have given the code of `event/index` gridview in the question and the code of action column.. Can you tell me how to do that???

Comment: ok..i will post my answer very soon.

Comment: @InsaneSkulll hey mate.. still waiting for the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91160/discussion-between-insane-skulll-and-mike-ross).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Example,

```
'buttons' => [
    'checkin/index' => function ($model) {
       return Html::a('<div id="notification-container"><span data-pjax=false class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>', Url::to(['checkin/index', 'title' => $model->title]), $options);
     }
],
```

In your `checkin/index`:

```
 $this->title => $_REQUSET['title'];
```

For more read [a()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#a%28%29-detail) and [to()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-baseurl.html#to%28%29-detail).

Comment: thank you for your help once again... it helped.. Had to modify it a little bit but solved my problem